# Disable dock button in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

For a MATLAB GUI I want to disable/remove the dock button in the upper right corner of the toolbar, is this possible?

It is possible to remove the whole toolbar, but I use some other options as well .

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can set it when you create the figure:

```
f = figure ( 'DockControls', 'off' )
```